# Rails: updating an ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone field with Time by update_attributes fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord, update-attributes

In Rails 3.1.3 with Postgresql, if you create an attribute as datetime, its class with ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone. However, anyone who can explain this:

```
user=User.first
user.update_attributes(:last_signed_in_at => Time.now) #True, but record isn't updated
user.update_attribute(:last_signed_in_at, Time.now) #True, and record is updated
user.last_signed_in_at = Time.now
user.save #True, and the record is updated
```

update_attributes is different from update_attribute that it checks validations. The only reason it fails might be:

```
user.last_signed_in_at = ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
Time.now.class = Time
```

Anyone who's able to sort it out?

Comment: do you have `attr_accessible` in your User model?

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude. attr_accessible: Specifies a white list of model attributes that can be set via mass-assignment, such as new(attributes), update_attributes(attributes), or attributes=(attributes)

Comment: So that fixes your problem :) ?

Comment: Yep, it has nothing to do with the time format. Appreciated!

Comment: Then I make it a clearer answer so the latecomer would know :)

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the `attr_accessible` being set in the User model.

What `update_attribtue` do is in fact very similar to calling `last_signed_in_at=`. see the source in http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute

One of the main differences between `update_attributes` and `update_attribute` is that `update_attributes` is to do mass-assignment while `update_attribute` is not.

That's why it is quite obvious that it is the `attr_accessible` problem.